# Want to prevent clipping of my output dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Card in which i have stacked a column of CaTeX widgets, but sometimes the CaTeX widgets are clipped of the screen and not all of the output in them is seen, I want to be able to possibly scroll the card when that happens so I can see the rest of the output. Most of the options i have used gave me a renderPage error, hasPos size error or NEED PAINT error.

like these
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U368a.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIAeS.png)

```dart
body: ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 0.0),
  children: [
    Card(
      child: Text("SOLUTION", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 28.0,
      ), ),
    ),
    Card(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: solution.map((sol) {
          return CaTeX(sol);
        }).toList(),
      )
    ),
  ],
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: give padding to the column

Comment: in this line `return CaTeX(sol);` wrap it with SizedBox with some `height:` and also wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` property